# PHP doesn't continue looping on second level with foreach in XML

Tags: php, xml, arrays, foreach, filezilla

**XML Code (FileZilla Server.xml):**

```
<FileZillaServer>
    <Users>
        <User Name="Bill">
            <Option Name="Pass">window</Option>
        </User>
        <User Name="Paul">
            <Option Name="Pass">apple</Option>
        </User>
    </Users>
</FileZillaServer>
```

**PHP Code:**

```
$filezilla = 'FileZilla Server.xml';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($filezilla);

foreach ($xml->Users->User as $user) {
    echo "<strong>".$user['Name']."</strong><br />";
        foreach ($xml->Users->User->Option as $option) {
            if ($option['Name'] == "Pass") {
                echo $option."<br />";
            }
        }
    echo "<br />";
}
```

**Output is:**

```
Bill
window

Paul
window
```

**Output should be:**

```
Bill
window

Paul
apple
```

It seems, that the inner foreach repeats itself without going further.
How can I correct this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `Option` is child of `User` you can't be expecting `$xml->Users->User->Option` to start at the current user node.

You could reference `Option` for the current `$user` as follows:

```
foreach ($xml->Users->User as $user) {
    echo "<strong>".$user['Name']."</strong><br />";
        foreach ($user->Option as $option) {
            if ($option['Name'] == "Pass") {
                echo $option."<br />";
            }
        }
    echo "<br />";
}
```